# Evaluating XPath function-based expressions in iOS

Tags: ios, xml, function, xpath, expression

Is there any way to evaluate xPath expressions in iOS?  For example, an expression like:

```
concat(xyz:field3, "!")
```

**EDIT**: I'm only concerned with function-based xPath expressions (e.g. concat, substring, abs)

I have tried using **stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString** to run the following script that takes an xPath expression and an XML file as input, but I am not getting any output.

```
    function evaluateXPath(inputXML,xPathExpr)
    {
        // load the XML document

        xmldoc=loadXMLDoc(inputXML);

        // process the input doc

        xPathResult = xmldoc.evaluate(xPathExpr, xmldoc, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);

        // convert result to string and return the string

        var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
        try {                        
            var str = serializer.serializeToString(xPathResult);                        
            // alert ("OUTPUT: "+str);                        
            return str; 
        }                    
        catch (e) {   
            // error catching stuff
        }  

    }
```